# how to set and retrieve data from the application context?

Tags: jsf-2

In my JSF application I need to store some data into the application context so that I can get it back. Is this possible and if yes then how to do this?

The reason I need to do this is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273846/session-scoped-bean-getting-recreated-for-every-request-upon-redirection

Answer (score 0):

Create a application scoped bean and store your data there.

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public void Bean {...}
```

Or access the application context directly by

```
ApplicationContext ctx = FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
```

Comment: How did you know OP is using Spring? Nothing in the question's body or tags indicates that.